# What to use to make an universal library for OS X and iOS Apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, static-libraries

for implementing my App I started to add controlling classes to an empty iOS project in Xcode.
My idea was to make an universal "Controller" for the iOS App and the OS X App.
So I also want to develop the controller separated from the UI part (of the dedicated app) with a separated Git repository.

*So my wish is: having an extra Xcode project for the library I can import both the iOS App and the OS X App for separated UI and controlling units development.*

**And my question: Is it possible to do like I want AND which type of library is best to build? There are 'Cocoa Library' and 'Cocoa Touch Library' as well as Bundles and other things.**

I'm not sure what's best to use and what are the actual differences between these things.
I'm also confused because it's called 'Cocoa' Library, as far as I know Cocoa is the framework for UI.

I would be happy to become a little bit unconfused and get some good answers, thank's :)